# How to automatically buid/compile the springboot + gradle application

Tags: java, gradle, build

I have to re-run the application everytime for every single change.

To run gradle app I use `gradle bootRun` (using Gradle 2.6) and my IDE of choice is Intellij Idea.

I also tried `spring-boot-devtools` but that did not work for me either.

How can I reload/re-compile the classes without re-running the the complete application every time?